# Use Loop in Crystal reports within the records in groups

Tags: foreach, crystal-reports

Report has been created using Crystal report and data has been grouped into several groups.

The requirement is, loop through records in individual groups to do some calculation. I.E. each group should display its own calculated value.

The calculation it not the problem, I need to know how to loop records inside individual group. Sample code is preferred.

Comment: take summary for every group using insert summary option

Comment: You can use a formula field to set your calculation and use a summary field over it instead of using a for loop ;).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to loop through records in Crystal Reports.

Comment: What do you need to calculate?

Where do you need to display the result of the calculation? Group header? Group Footer? Report Footer?